# How to apply styling on input tags individually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a input list coming from modal window so these are selected names displaying in input field, Now i want to apply styling on names so it can display as separate names , I know i am using `join(;)` for separator between names but that's not enough.

How can i add styling that can be more readable for the users , like if i can apply background color to each of selected items that will be better.

main.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  customReadOnly"
        style="font-size: 20px; background-color:red"
        id="prcsOwner" required ng-model="processOwnerObj.workerName"
        name="prcsOwner" readonly="readonly"
        placeholder="Process Owner" />
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.processOwnerObj.workerName= $scope.selectedOwners.map(function (owner) { return owner.fullName; }).join(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot user ng-model that way...
You might have to use $parsers and $formatters in a directive

See [here](http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.ca/2014/04/ParsersAndFormattersInCustomValidationDirectivesInAngularJS.html) and [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)...